# MetaPost: Adjust colour value (brightness/luminosity)

Tags: color, context, metapost, transparency

## Background

In MetaPost, colours can be lightened or darkened by calling the transparency function. However, this allows other colours to show through, which isn't necessarily desirable all the time. Sometimes a colour should be lightened or darkened independently of its transparency, by changing its **value**.

## Problem

Colours can be adjusted in MetaPost with multiplication, such as:

```
\definecolor[BaseColour][h=66CEF1]

\startuseMPgraphic{page:ThemeElement}
  color baseColour;
  baseColour := .5 * \MPcolor{BaseColour};
\stopuseMPgraphic
```

However, that changes the **saturation**, and possibly the **hue** as well.

## Question

In MetaPost, how do you control a colour's **value**, **saturation**, and **hue**, independently?

## Related

The following ConTeXt code illustrates, conceptually at least, what I'd like to do in MetaPost:

```
\definecolor[BaseColour][h=66CEF1]
\definespotcolor[BaseColourSaturation][BaseColour][s=.625]
\definespotcolor[BaseColourValue][BaseColour][value=.625]
\definespotcolor[BaseColourHue][BaseColour][hue=.625]
```

The MetaPost Applications manual defines:

```
SetupColors( auto-SV, shading-SV, grayscale )
```

From the mailing list:

- http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2011/063073.html

It appears that these functions all render the same output when viewed in Evince (the PDF reader I am using).

From the [manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf%E2%80%8E) you can employ a complementary factor:

```
.7[red,white]
```

For example:

```
fill unitsquare scaled 1cm withcolor .7[red,white];
```

However, this does not provide enough control.

Comment: Do `withrgbcolor` or `withcmykcolor` give you enough control?  You can find HSV to RGB/CMYK algorithms [easily enough](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hsv-to-rgb.htm).

Comment: `withcmykcolor` is not required, MetaFun assumes a CMYK colour  if a colour with four elements is provided and interprets it correctly. HSV is not supported, though (well, strictly speaking CMYK is not supported either).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ConTeXt features several colour conversions, which are built into the core:

- CMYK to grey
- CMYK to RGB
- grey to HSV
- HSV to grey
- HSV to RGB
- RGB to CMYK
- RGB to grey
- RGB to HSV

They are defined in the file
[`attr-col.lua`](https://gitorious.org/context/context/source/b76759d73e6734cb014fe46da1f8521dcc9a8d71:tex/context/base/attr-col.lua).
Here I use the Lua function
[`hsvtorgb`](https://gitorious.org/context/context/source/b76759d73e6734cb014fe46da1f8521dcc9a8d71:tex/context/base/attr-col.lua#L155-180)
to convert the HSV input to an RGB value which MetaPost understands. The
interface is not pretty, but it should get you started. Feel free to create a MetaPost definition for the conversion.

```
%% macros=mkvi

\starttexdefinition hsvtorgb #h #s #v
  \ctxlua{context("(\letterpercent f, \letterpercent f, \letterpercent f)", attributes.colors.hsvtorgb(#h, #s, #v))}
\stoptexdefinition

\starttext

Hues

\dostepwiserecurse{0}{360}{20}{\dontleavehmode
  \startMPcode
    fill unitcircle scaled 1cm withcolor \hsvtorgb{\recurselevel}{.76}{.76};
  \stopMPcode}

Saturation

\dorecurse{19}{\dontleavehmode
  \startMPcode
    fill unitcircle scaled 1cm withcolor \hsvtorgb{120}{.04*\recurselevel}{.76};
  \stopMPcode}

Value

\dorecurse{19}{\dontleavehmode
  \startMPcode
    fill unitcircle scaled 1cm withcolor \hsvtorgb{120}{.76}{.04*\recurselevel};
  \stopMPcode}

\stoptext
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that allows plain Metapost to use HSV colours.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

vardef hsv_color(expr h,s,v) =
    % following wikipedia article on "HSL and HSV"
    save chroma, hh, x, m;
    chroma = v*s;
    hh = h/60;
    x  = chroma * (1-abs(hh mod 2 - 1));
    m  = v - chroma;
    if     hh < 1: (chroma,x,0)+(m,m,m)
    elseif hh < 2: (x,chroma,0)+(m,m,m)
    elseif hh < 3: (0,chroma,x)+(m,m,m)
    elseif hh < 4: (0,x,chroma)+(m,m,m)
    elseif hh < 5: (x,0,chroma)+(m,m,m)
    else:          (chroma,0,x)+(m,m,m)
    fi
enddef;

beginfig(1);
label.rt("Hue",        (-12,96));
label.rt("Saturation", (-12,64));
label.rt("Value",      (-12,32));
for i=0 upto 18:
   fill fullcircle scaled 20 shifted (20i,80) withcolor hsv_color(20i,3/4,3/4);
   fill fullcircle scaled 20 shifted (20i,48) withcolor hsv_color(120,i/25,3/4);
   fill fullcircle scaled 20 shifted (20i,16) withcolor hsv_color(120,3/4,i/25);
endfor
endfig;

beginfig(2);
for h=10 step 10 until 360:
  for s = 0.2 step 0.1 until 1:
     fill fullcircle scaled 20 shifted (100s*right) rotated h  withcolor hsv_color(h,s,1);
  endfor
  label(decimal floor(1/2+h), 110 right rotated h);
endfor
endfig;
end.
```

The first of the example figures looks like this:
[image]

The second shows a colour wheel with `v=1`, `h` varying round the wheel, and `s` decreasing nearer the middle.

[image: an HSV colour wheel]

The colours are all flat: the apparent gradients (particularly obvious in the orange-red area) are an optical illusion.

Comment: Recently wrote something similar in [XSL](http://djarvis.bitbucket.org/xml/colour.xsl) to create a [pie chart](http://djarvis.bitbucket.org/xml/resources.html) that chooses wedge colours for an arbitrary number of slices, all based on a given starting colour. Wouldn't be hard to extend this to pie charts in MetaPost.